# Very hard object-oriented "transplantation"in android

Tags: java, android, oop

In my android app there are at least 4 places where the user can click a photo and then get a dialog saying "take a photo or pick from gallery to change your picture"
in each of these places its a different activity with different variables and different xml element names and I have a lot of really similar code, repeated through out my app.

I want to take it out in a separate class, but is so tangled up in the code that it feels like a heart transplantation. My object-oriented skills and Java skills arent that great (3 months experience) and maybe there is some workaround in Android that I dont know about.

I will provide two examples from different classes so you get an idea of how much repetition there is. I will be very grateful if someone could help me produce a separate object out of this

Settings class, image changer excerpt:

```
iUserAvatarSettings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Settings.this, R.style.no_title_dialog);
                if (!userHasProvidedOwnPhoto) {
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.signup_avatar_upload_dialog);
                } else {
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.signup_avatar_upload_dialog_2);
                    bDeleteAvatar = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bDeleteAvatar);
                    try {
                        bDeleteAvatar.setTypeface(font1);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    bDeleteAvatar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            setAvatarPath("default_avatar");
                            userHasProvidedOwnPhoto = false;
                            if (userSex.equals("Male") || userSex.equals("")) {
                                iUserAvatarSettings.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar_default_male);

                            } else {
                                iUserAvatarSettings.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar_default_female);
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
                Button bTakeAPhoto = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bTakeAPhoto);
                Button bSelectPhotoFromFile = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bSelectPhotoFromFile);
                Button bCancelAvatarUpload = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bCancelAvatarUpload);
                try {
                    bTakeAPhoto.setTypeface(font1);
                    bSelectPhotoFromFile.setTypeface(font1);
                    bCancelAvatarUpload.setTypeface(font1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                bTakeAPhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (isIntentAvailable(Settings.this, MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)) {
                            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA);

                            dialog.dismiss();

                        } else {
                            toastMaker.toast(net.asdqwe.activities.Settings.this, Configurationz.ErrorMessages.DEVICE_UNABLE_TO_TAKE_PHOTOS,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            userHasProvidedOwnPhoto = false;
                        }
                    }
                });

                bSelectPhotoFromFile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent getImageFromGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        getImageFromGallery.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(getImageFromGallery, PICK_IMAGE);
                        //avatarPath = saveUserAvatar.getUserAvatar().toString();
                        //setAvatarPath(saveUserAvatar.getUserAvatar().toString()); // this remains under question
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                bCancelAvatarUpload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        }); // end of image button on click handling

    public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;
    }

    private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {

        try {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            iUserAvatarSettings.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
            saveUserAvatar.SaveImage(this, mImageBitmap);
            userHasProvidedOwnPhoto = true;
            setAvatarPath(saveUserAvatar.getUserAvatar().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            toastMaker.toast(net.asdqwe.activities.Settings.this, Configurationz.ErrorMessages.TAKING_PHOTO_FAILED,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            userHasProvidedOwnPhoto = false;
        }

    }

    private void handleGalleryPhoto(Intent intent) {
        try {
            Uri _uri = intent.getData();
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
            cursor.close();
            mImageBitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath);
            iUserAvatarSettings.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap2);
            saveUserAvatar.SaveImage(this, mImageBitmap2);
            userHasProvidedOwnPhoto = true;
            setAvatarPath(saveUserAvatar.getUserAvatar().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            toastMaker.toast(net.zxcasd.activities.Settings.this, Configurationz.ErrorMessages.PICKING_PHOTO_FROM_GALLERY_FAILED,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            userHasProvidedOwnPhoto = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            handleSmallCameraPhoto(data);

        } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            handleGalleryPhoto(data);
        }
    }
```

Signup class, image excerpt:

```
iUserAvatar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Signup.this, R.style.no_title_dialog);
            if (!userHasProvidedOwnPhoto) {
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.signup_avatar_upload_dialog);
            } else {
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.signup_avatar_upload_dialog_2);
                bDeleteAvatar = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bDeleteAvatar);
                try {
                    bDeleteAvatar.setTypeface(font1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                bDeleteAvatar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        userHasProvidedOwnPhoto = false;
                        if (userSex.equals("Male") || userSex.equals("")) {
                            iUserAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar_default_male);
                        } else {
                            iUserAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar_default_female);
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
            Button bTakeAPhotoSignupPage = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bTakeAPhoto);
            Button bSelectPhotoFromFileSignupPage = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bSelectPhotoFromFile);
            Button bCancelAvatarUpload = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bCancelAvatarUpload);
            try {
                bTakeAPhotoSignupPage.setTypeface(font1);
                bSelectPhotoFromFileSignupPage.setTypeface(font1);
                bCancelAvatarUpload.setTypeface(font1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            bTakeAPhotoSignupPage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (isIntentAvailable(Signup.this, MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)) {
                        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA);
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    } else {
                        toastMaker.toast(net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this, Configurationz.ErrorMessages.DEVICE_UNABLE_TO_TAKE_PHOTOS,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        userHasProvidedOwnPhoto = false;
                    }
                }
            });

            bSelectPhotoFromFileSignupPage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent getImageFromGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    getImageFromGallery.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(getImageFromGallery, PICK_IMAGE);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            bCancelAvatarUpload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // and deal with photo
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {

    try {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iUserAvatar.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        saveUserAvatar.SaveImage(this, mImageBitmap);
        userHasProvidedOwnPhoto = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        toastMaker.toast(net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this, Configurationz.ErrorMessages.TAKING_PHOTO_FAILED,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        userHasProvidedOwnPhoto = false;
    }

}

private void handleGalleryPhoto(Intent intent) {
    try {
        Uri _uri = intent.getData();
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.close();
        mImageBitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath);
        iUserAvatar.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap2);
        saveUserAvatar.SaveImage(this, mImageBitmap2);
        userHasProvidedOwnPhoto = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        toastMaker.toast(net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this, Configurationz.ErrorMessages.PICKING_PHOTO_FROM_GALLERY_FAILED,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        userHasProvidedOwnPhoto = false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        handleSmallCameraPhoto(data);

    } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        handleGalleryPhoto(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried in your [refactoring](http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=4) efforts so far? Are you using an IDE? Does it provide refactoring tools?

Comment: Well I have two ideas at the moment - take out those three methods at the end of each excerpt to a separate class and also using the same xml dialog for both cases. Im using Eclipse IDE and I havent used its refactoring tools (if there are any)

Comment: Each time you create a `new OnClickListener()`, they could be a seperate class which extends the OnClickListener class. Then you could call a `new extendedListener()` and not have to repaste the overrided method.

Comment: Try selecting some code; right clicking and selecting Refactor -> Extract Method.

Comment: is the ide smart enough not to mess this up?

Comment: Try it. Eclipse is pretty smart and will usually produce working code.

Comment: @J.Kowalski would you still be interested in an alternate answer or is your problem resolved?

Comment: I followed Chris' answer and I improvised and I made this work :) But if you want you can share you knowledge, everyone will benefit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Move `isIntentAvailable(Context, String)` into an utility class. This could be helpful in some other uses cases.
2. Create a abstract class (refered to as *MyAbstractActivity*) which contains all common activity methods: `handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent)`, `handleGalleryPhoto(Intent)` and `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)`

   - `iUserAvatarSettings` / `iUserAvatar` must be part of *MyAbstractActivity*. If you need different implementations of it for different use cases, create an abstract getter, f.e. `getUserAvatarButton()`.
   - `setAvatarPath(String)` is only used in one of the two classes. Make it an abstract method in *MyAbstractActivity* and implement it as needed.
   - Let the other classes inherit from *MyAbstractActivity*.
3. Transform the OnClickListener into a class.

   - As constructor arguments you pass a subclass of *MyAbstractActivity* and a Button (`iUserAvatarSettings` / `iUserAvatar`).
   - Use the constructor arguments to refer to methods and variables like `userHasProvidedOwnPhoto`.
   - The `iUserAvatar.setOnClickListener(...)` part will remain in *MyAbstractActivity*.
4. Now you have removed the code redundancy, but there will be more to do. Probably encapsulation isn't good enough right now.

   - Think about moving methods and variables to the OnClickListener class or away from it.
   - Think about moving methods and variables to *MyAbstractActivity* or away from it.
   - Ask some more experienced developer to make a review. (Don't ask him to refactor it.)
   - If you have specific refactoring question come back her and ask the community.

Answer (score 1):

You can check my project [Android Image Helper](https://github.com/sherifelkhatib/Android-Image-Helper) on Github

An activity with image selection feature would look something like this:

```
public class ImageUploaderActivity extends Activity implements ImageChooseCallback {
    ImageUploadEngine uploadEngine;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uploadEngine = new ImageUploadEngine.Builder(this, savedInstanceState).build();
        //...
        someButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadEngine.performImageAsk(R.string.app_name, R.string.newphoto, R.string.oldphoto, R.string.choose, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        uploadEngine.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(uploadEngine.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) return;
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCanceled(ImageUploadEngine engine) {
        //notifying you that the user has canceled the request
    }

    @Override
    public void onChosen(ImageUploadEngine engine, String path, boolean newPicture) {
        //notifying you that the user has selected an image
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ImageUploadEngine engine, Exception ex) {
        //notifying you that an error has occurred
    }
}
```

The uploadEngine also exposes functions performImageTake and performImageChoose in case the default dialog (to choose) does not suit your needs.

**FYI:**

This project aims to provide an easy-to-use instrument for android developers to use when they need the user to select an image on their android phone and upload it. If the process has any errors on specific phones, these should be handled inside the library to provide the same user experience on all phones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to refactor your code. I have tried to give some justification about my design as well.

**1) You could abstract away the dialog into a widget.**

You can create a `PhotoPickerDialog` that extends `Dialog` and provides desired functionality. Then you can re-use this widget at different places / activities.

```
public class PhotoPickerDialog extends Dialog {

    //private fields
    private Typeface buttonFont = Typeface.DEFAULT;
    private Button bTakeAPhoto;
    private Button bSelectPhotoFromFile;
    private Button bCancelAvatarUpload;
    private IMediaHelper mMediaHelper;

    public PhotoPickerDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    public PhotoPickerDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
        initView();
    }

    protected PhotoPickerDialog(Context context, boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
        initView();
    }

    protected void setLayoutResource() {
        setContentView(R.layout.signup_avatar_upload_dialog);
    }

    protected void initView() {
        setLayoutResource();

        bTakeAPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTakeAPhoto);
        bSelectPhotoFromFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSelectPhotoFromFile);
        bCancelAvatarUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCancelAvatarUpload);

        bCancelAvatarUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Set the type face of the button, in case you want to have different
     * font at different times.
     */
    public void setButtonFont(Typeface font) {
        buttonFont = font;
        bTakeAPhoto.setTypeface(buttonFont);
        bSelectPhotoFromFile.setTypeface(buttonFont);
        bCancelAvatarUpload.setTypeface(buttonFont);
    }

    /**
     * Set the media helper object which implements the functionality to
     * take and pick photo. So the task delegated to this media helper.
     */
    public void setMediaHelper(IMediaHelper mediaHelper) {
        mMediaHelper = mediaHelper;
        bTakeAPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMediaHelper.takePhoto();
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        bSelectPhotoFromFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMediaHelper.pickPhoto();
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Since you need two different types of dialogs depending on whether the user has a avatar photo already or not. Let us create a `PhotoPickerDialogWithDelete` that extends `PhotoPickerDialog`. Then we just have to `override` a few methods and add the delete callback to make our new type of dialog without re-writing a lot of code.

```
public class PhotoPickerDialogWithDelete extends PhotoPickerDialog {
    private Button bDeleteAvatar;

    public PhotoPickerDialogWithDelete(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PhotoPickerDialogWithDelete(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
    }

    protected PhotoPickerDialogWithDelete(Context context, boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setLayoutResource() {
        setContentView(R.layout.signup_avatar_upload_dialog_2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initView() {
        super.initView();
        bDeleteAvatar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDeleteAvatar);
    }

    @Override
    public void setButtonFont(Typeface font) {
        super.setButtonFont(font);
        bDeleteAvatar.setTypeface(font);
    }

    public void setOnDeleteListener(final View.OnClickListener listener) {
        bDeleteAvatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
                listener.onClick(v);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**2) Move the photo intent related functionality to an `abstract` base class `MediaSupportActivity`.**

All the activities that need to support taking/picking photos just need to `extend` from this class and implement two simple methods `handleSmallCameraPhoto(Bitmap)` and `handleGalleryPhoto(Bitmap)`. They do not have to explicitly care about how to take/pick photos, but only care about how to handle them (which can be different for different activities).

```
public abstract class MediaSupportActivity extends Activity implements IMediaHelper {

    private static final int TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA = 1;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 2;

    protected abstract void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Bitmap image);
    protected abstract void handleGalleryPhoto(Bitmap image);

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            handleSmallCameraPhoto(bitmap);
        }
        else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri _uri = data.getData();
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
            cursor.close();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath);
            handleGalleryPhoto(bitmap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void takePhoto() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, MediaSupportActivity.TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void pickPhoto() {
        Intent getImageFromGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        getImageFromGallery.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(getImageFromGallery, MediaSupportActivity.PICK_IMAGE);
    }
}
```

3) There is an interface `IBBMediaHelper` that defined two methods: `takePhoto()` and `pickPhoto()`. We pass a `IBBMediaHelper` instance to the dialog, so that that dialog does not have full access to the other properties and methods of the `MediaSupportActivity`

```
public interface IMediaHelper {

    public void takePhoto();

    public void pickPhoto();
}
```

4) Here is a sample how to use the above classes together:

```
public class MainActivity extends MediaSupportActivity {

    Button iUserAvatarSettings;
    private boolean userHasProvidedOwnPhoto = false;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        iUserAvatarSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        iUserAvatarSettings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final PhotoPickerDialog dialog;
                if (!userHasProvidedOwnPhoto) {
                    dialog = new PhotoPickerDialog(MainActivity.this);
                }
                else {
                    dialog = new PhotoPickerDialogWithDelete(MainActivity.this);
                    ((PhotoPickerDialogWithDelete)dialog).setOnDeleteListener(onAvatarDelete);
                }
                dialog.setButtonFont(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
                dialog.setMediaHelper(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Bitmap image) {
        // sample code
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleGalleryPhoto(Bitmap image) {
        // sample code
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    }

    private OnClickListener onAvatarDelete = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // this is executed when delete is clicked
            // check for male/female and update the avatar
            // etc. etc.
        }
    };
}
```

**Update:** You can also create an avatar widget `AvatarWidget` class that contains an `ImageView` and `PhotoPickerDialog`. This class encapsulates the logic of displaying an avatar, clicking on it to show the menu and setting the default avatar when delete is clicked. Then in the main activity, simply declare your avatar widget via code or XML and call the setters on it when the image is received.